# Where is rdbuf()->str()?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the structure of IO stream.
From [cppreference *std::basic_stringstream::str*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)  :

> Manages the contents of the underlying string object.
>
> 1) Returns a copy of the underlying string as if by calling `rdbuf()->str()`.

`rdbuf()` returns a `std::basic_streambuf` object, but I can't find a `str()` member function in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look again more carefully.  [`std::basic_stringstream::rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/rdbuf) actually returns a pointer to a [`std::basic_stringbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf), not a pointer to a [`std::basic_streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) as you claim.

[`str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str) is a method of [`std:::basic_stringbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf).

Comment: Why I got it wrong it's that I went to the `std::basic_ios::rdbuf` page directly. So it seems that `std::basic_stringstream` overrides the `rdbuf` function.

Comment: @Rick not "override", since `rdbuf()` is not virtual.